# Loading javascript conditionally in Wordpress functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I created a child theme of the TwentyTwelve theme in Wordpress for my photography website.

In the photo gallery pages, clicking on a thumbnail image either triggers Fancybox or Photoswipe, depending on the screen size (if <500px Photoswipe is used as it's probably a mobile device).

For better performance I would like to load only the required javascript, Fancybox or Photoswipe, but not both of them.

- I'm not using plugins for Fancybox/Photoswipe but load them in the child theme functions.php using wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script
- the choice between Fancybox/Photoswipe is made in another javascript file, also enqueued in functions.php: according to the result of jQuery(window).width(); it triggers either Fancybox or Photoswipe on certain elements:

  ```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      windows_size = jQuery(window).width();

      if(  windows_size > 500) {                  // Load Fancybox

         jQuery(".brick a").fancybox({

         [...]

      else {          // Load Photoswipe

         jQuery(".brick a").photoSwipe({

         [...]
  ```
- I cannot use any of the WP functions like is_page(...), as both scripts are fired on the same page
- I don't know if it would be possible, using Wordpress, to load all required files for Photoswipe (js and css) in the javascript above
- I'd rather not use the user-agent to detect a mobile device

I searched on Google and on StackOverflow but couldn't find any answer specifically related to Wordpress and this situation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As far as I know, the enqueuing can only be stopped at PHP level. And [looks like](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%22screen+size%22) PHP cannot detect screen sizes. Take a look at [wordpress.se] too.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this the other day, and it looks like he's trying to do the same thing as you -- "How to load JavaScript conditionally with media queries in WordPress":

http://blog.logo24.com/2013/07/23/javascript-media-queries-wordpress/

His solution is JavaScript, rather than PHP, and comes with some caveats.